# C# - Exe application crashes when try to load an xml file at init

Tags: c#, .net, xml

I have a windows form application that in a certain moment (on a click event), save data to a xml file. This xml file will be used when application start again (I check if the file exists). In debug/release mode works perfectly but when I use the exe version (the version that gonna be used in others computers), the app can't start.

I can see the file that was created in my computer (AppData/Local...).

In my code, the file is save it into the Debug/Release folder.

```
if (System.IO.File.Exists("recover.xml"))
{
    LoadXML();
 }
```

And I save it

```
XmlSerializer xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(ConsoleData));

StreamWriter myWriter = new StreamWriter( "recover.xml" );
xmlSerializer.Serialize(myWriter, data);
myWriter.Close();
```

Where the problem could come?
Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by "crashes"? Can you show us some code?

Comment: Are you reading the file from right place?

Comment: We need to know what the error is or see the code you're using to retrieve the file.

Comment: You are probably not specifying path for your file properly, so in Visual studio it is using default debug/release folder, but when you deploy it it is trying to use a different path than that and hence crashing,

Comment: You're not including your code to create or read the XML file, or the error that occurs. I'll be exactly as descriptive with my answer. "Something is wrong." Hope that helps.

Comment: Sorry!, FileStream xmlFile = new FileStream(FILE_XML, FileMode.Open); where FILE_XML="file.xml"

Comment: That sentence I use to create the xml file.

Comment: Why is one "recover.xml" and the other is "file.xml" ?

Comment: I use a file name that I don't want to show in public, I forget that in the question have put "recover.xml". The important is that I use a filename without specify a path. Anyway, the problem was resolved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I 've analyzed the situation and searching any problem in my source but I realized that the way that I was using the xml file (load and save) was correct. So, I started to search line by line after load data from the xml and I saw that the problem was in other site. The result from the xml was correctly.
I apologize, this question was wrong. 
I'll check things better next time.